# Help with delta function probblem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

Find a solution to

$[g(x)u'(x)]'=\delta(x)$

$-\infty<x<\infty$.

What i have so far:

$[g(x)u'(x)]'=g(x)u''(x)+g'(x)u'(x)=\delta(x)$

$\Rightarrow u''(x)+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}u'(x)=\frac{\delta(x)}{g(x)}$.

This is where i'm stuck, since what i know form my course of differential equations i only know how to solve when dealing with constant coefficients. Any hints or guidence would be greatly aprreciated.

I forgot to say that $g^{-1}$ is integrable.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate once directly,
$$
g(x)u'(x)=H(x)+C
$$
with $H$ the Heaviside function of a jump from zero to one at zero. After that you just have to integrate
$$
g(x)=D+\int\frac{H(x)+C}{g(x)}dx
$$
and fix constants to fit initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $x\ne 0$, we can write

$$(g(x)u'(x))'=0$$

Therefore, we find that

$$ u(x)=\begin{cases}C^+\int_0^x \frac{1}{g(t)}\,dt+K^+&,x>0\\\\C^-\int_0^x \frac{1}{g(t)}\,dt+K^-&,x<0
\end{cases}$$

Since $u$ is continuous at $x=0$, then $K^+=K^-=u(0)$.  Furthermore, $u'$ is discontinuous at $x=0$ with $u'(0^+)-u'(0^-)=1/g(0)$.  Thus, $C^-=C^+-1$.  Therefore, we can write

$$ u(x)=\begin{cases}C^+\int_0^x \frac{1}{g(t)}\,dt+u(0)&,x>0\\\\(C^+-1)\int_0^x \frac{1}{g(t)}\,dt+u(0)&,x<0
\end{cases}$$